# How merge datas in effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a service which returns a list of items and effect which listens to this service

```
    loadBanners$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(BannerActions.loadBanners),
            switchMap((s) =>
                this.bannersService.getAll(s.filter).pipe(
                    map((response) => BannerActions.loadBannersSuccess({ response })),
                    catchError((error) => of(BannerActions.loadBannersFail({ error })))
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

In the response I have item code values and I want to display item names, which comes from another service

```
  getDictionary(codeId: string): Observable<DictionaryListResponse> {
    return this._httpClient.post<DictionaryListResponse>(this.apiUrl, { codeId: codeId});
  }
```

Now the question is how combine this two services and get full data with code and names?